# Animating an object within bounds in a direction

Tags: animation

So just for kicks, I've decided to whip up a "tower defense" game. I have all of the core concepts down. There is just one aspect that i haven't really figured out yet.

**What is the best approach to animating objects along a path?**

I don't want the path to be too rigid, I'd like there to be a little bit of minor variance.

I'm thinking almost like a "river" that the objects float down, where there are banks that the objects cannot pass, and a flow that defines the direction. If an object hits a bank, it should just kinda bounce off the edge towards the center of the "river" and always be heading "down stream"

I'd like answers to stay away from frameworks as much as is reasonable. And I don't think language should matter too much (feel free to post code/psuedo code if it illustrates the process better though!).

**EDIT:**
Now that I'm thinking about it, would something like an A* path finding (or other if A* doesn't make sense, that's just the main one i know of) approach be reasonable? There is of course a concept of an "exit" where the objects are trying to go, so I suppose I could just have a rule that says "these pixels are impassable, what's the shortest route to the exit". And add a ever so slight amount of variance to route if needed.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this issue:

[image: Pathfinding]

In this image, the brown path represents the path your baddies are going to take, the yellow squares are waypoints, and the red edges are path boundaries.  Here's basically how their state could progress:

```
Have I hit a waypoint?
  Yes, adjust my forward axis
    Choose the next waypoint
    My forward direction is toward that waypoint
Am I touching a red boundary?
  No, I can wander left or right
  Yes, it's on my right
    I should wander left
  Yes, it's on my left
    I should wander right
Add lateral movement based on the wander direction I've chosen
```

There are a few variables that could be fine tuned here:

- Baddies should commit to one direction for a given amount of time unless they hit a waypoint so they don't jitter
- When they encounter a path border, they should progress away from it for a set amount so that they don't bounce against it
- Baddies should hit the center of waypoints before progressing to the next.  Otherwise, they may get caught on sharp corners.

If your levels are pre-generated (which I believe is the case for most TD games) then you can set the waypoints when you create the maps.  If you're procedurally generating them, then just place waypoints where you'd like the downstream of your river to change by more than +/- five degrees.  A* is a bit of overkill for such a constrained domain.  If you want to add a little bit more variability, you could consider branching paths in which baddies choose their next waypoint from a selection at random, you could set up a T junction where baddies visit A, then B, then C, then B, then D.  It should be pretty easy to prototype, and the right feel will come with some tweaking in how much lateral movement you allow or encourage.